# Using LifecycleProcessor and start signal (with @Autowire in @SpringBootApplication)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have simple application based on Spring Boot.

I don't use any XML configuration in this example.

Main component is `appMain` (using implicit constructor autowiring) and it depends on `dataCollector` that implements `LifecycleProcessor`. It overrides and defines `public void start()` which I'd expect that will be called right after the Spring container is created.

According to documentation:

"Any Spring-managed object may implement that interface. Then, when the ApplicationContext itself receives start and stop signals, e.g. for a stop/restart scenario at runtime, it will cascade those calls to all Lifecycle implementations defined within that context."

But this `start` method is never invoked. So is `start signal` something that has to be explicitly defined and sent towards ApplicationContext? Isn't it done always when container start? I thought that it is a part of container lifecycle but it seems not that way. How is it done then?

I need some parallel deamon-like thread that starts and stops with whole my application. Is this LifecycleProcessor something i should use or is there some better option in Spring?

**AppMain**

```
import org.springframework.boot.Banner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@SpringBootApplication
@DependsOn("dataCollector")
public class AppMain {

    public LocColMain(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        context.registerShutdownHook();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(AppMain.class);
        app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

**DataCollector**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.LifecycleProcessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Random;

@Component
public class DataCollector implements LifecycleProcessor {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataCollector.class);

    private boolean isRunning;

    private final DaoRssiCache daoRssiCache;

    public DataCollector(DaoRssiCache daoRssiCache) {
        this.daoRssiCache = daoRssiCache;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        log.info("Data collector - REFRESH.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose() {
        log.info("Data collector - CLOSE.");

        stop();
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        log.info("Data collector - DESTROY.");

        stop();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.info("Data collector - CREATED.");
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        log.info("Data collector - START.");

        isRunning = true;

        while (isRunning) {
            // TODO: do some business stuff...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        log.info("Data collector - STOP.");
        isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need parallel thread for background job, then you should create it. According to your requirements thread can be `daemon`. If you do not need to wait until thread done its job, you can specify it as deamon, and after shutdown of the app - this thread will be interrupted without timeout.

Example:

```
class BackgroundJob extends Thread {
    public BackgroundJob(boolean daemon) {
        setDaemon(daemon);
    }
    //others logic
}
```